# JAVA method that computes and prints a total sum of items

Tags: java

Please I am struggling with JAVA as I am a beginner. What I am supposed to do is to:

Add some necessary statements to the `printOrderCost()` method in the main class so that this method computes and prints the total cost of all beer items in the order. (This method calls the `getCost()` method for each beer item, accumulates the sum of all of the `getCost()` values, and then prints the sum – the total cost of all beer objects.)

```
public static void printOrderCost(Beer[] order)
 {
  double totalCost;
  int count;

 }


 }

 public double getCost()
 {
   double cost;
   cost = quantity * itemCost;
   return (cost);

 }

 public String toString()  // not necessary to format the output
 {
   String s;
   s = brand + " ";
   s += quantity + " " ;
   s += itemCost + " ";
   s += getCost();

   return s;


 }
```

output:

```
Bud 5 3.0 15.0
Canadian 5 1.0 5.0
Blue 3 2.0 6.0
White Seal 4 1.0 4.0
Bud Light 1 2.0 2.0
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Your output doesn't seem to match the code you've posted. Why is it so?!

Comment: I must need a beer when we start getting these questions :P

Comment: What are you seeing, @MadProgrammer? I'm seeing the same question, word for word.

Comment: I reposted the question, to ask about another thing and to get my topic up the list of questions

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta No sorry my bad, I read the last one to be about extending the output of `toString` and this one to be about the `totalCost`, man, I need that beer :P

Answer (score 2):

Start with a `for-loop`, call `getCost` on each item, print the results.

```
public static void printOrderCost(Beer[] order) {
    double totalCost = 0;
    int count = order.length;
    for (Beer beer : order) {
        // Use beer.getCost() and add it to the totalCost
    }
    // Print the results...
}
```

Take a look at [The for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for more details

Comment: Is `int count = order.length;` really required? #JustCurious :)

Comment: @R.J No, and it might cause a `NullPointerException` as well, but it seemed to be a requirement, so I filled it..."You have n beer @ a total cost of $xxxx"....

Comment: @R.J Final result `10 beers cost is 111000 million dollars`  :) , where 10 is count.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ You must drink some nice beer 8P

Comment: MadProgrammer - I missed that last part in the question. Just re-read it:) @Suresh - Super costly beer I must say :D

Comment: the total cost of all the 5 different brands of beer with quantity of each brand should add up to 32

Comment: @CanadaTom-I suggest you first implement that method. The count and the sum would fall into place automatically.

Comment: R.J ok, I will try of course, but I do not know how to add in java i mean adding beer.getCost() to the totalCost

Comment: @CanadaTom `result = result + a`...or, if you're really lazy, `result += a`